# Best pratice for SSL in CakePHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, ssl, https

I'd like to implement HTTPS for all pages.

I use CakePHP 2.3 with the "Auth" component.

Actually the only one way I found is to add a "beforeFilter-condition".

But this is very dirty because I have a lot of "not-SSL" requests because of Auth-Component.

*AppController.php* --->

```
class AppController extends Controller {

  public function beforeFilter() {
    if (env("SERVER_PORT") != "443") {
      $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'forceSSL';
      $this->Security->requireSecure();
    }
  }

  public function forceSSL() {
    $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here);
  }

}
```

The problem appears when I am not logged in and I try to access my website

- *Request --> Response    (because of)*
- GET hxxp://MYSITE/ --> **302** hxxp**s**://MYSITE/    (beforeFilter-redirection)
- GET hxxp**s**://MYSITE/ --> **302** hxxp://MYSITE/users/login    (Auth component)
- GET hxxp://MYSITE/users/login --> **302** hxxp**s**://MYSITE/users/login    (beforeFilter-redirection)
- GET hxxp**s**://MYSITE/users/login --> **200**
- POST hxxp**s**://MYSITE/users/login (with creds) --> **302** hxxp://MYSITE/    (Auth component)
- GET hxxp://MYSITE/ --> **302** hxxp**s**://MYSITE/
- GET hxxp**s**://MYSITE/ --> **200**

SO, do you know another way to do that.

NB: I had to force secure my cookie in core.php because they weren't.

core.php --->

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'php',
  'ini' => array(
    'session.cookie_secure' => true
  )));
```

Note that I also tried to force SSL by modifying .htaccess but all I get is infinite loop.

EDIT :

The default .htaccess in CakePHP is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I tried to add :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I would say that if you want **all** your site's pages then this would be a job for Apache or IIS and how your hosts are mapped. I know you've said you've tried to modify .htaccess but I truly believe this is the right thing to do.

Comment: @sam-delaney Hum, right but do you know the way to do that on Cake2.3 ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which version of CakePHP you're using since what I'm suggesting applies to the software which sits under PHP which is usually Apache (but could be IIS or others). Apache is what reads your .htaccess files. A quick Google resulted in this [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html) which may assist you. Is this on you're local machine? Are you running a WAMP stack or something similar?

Comment: Yes I know what a htaccess is :) But what I said is when I tried (edit on my post) I had an infinite loop because of incompatibility between lines.

Comment: When I looked up your .htaccess configuration I found a slightly different layout (http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ssl-example-usage-in-htaccess.html#sub-server_port). Where are you being redirected to?

Comment: Check the .htaccess of Html5Boilerplate. It is **very** well documented and contains a lot of other optimisations to learn from; [H5BP .htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) - look somewhere around line 328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the solution I chose was:

- Deleting /app/webroot/.htaccess and /app/.htaccess
- Modifying /.htaccess to

.htaccess --->

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

- Disabling URL-Rewriting in Cake

core.php --->

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

Now access is via **hxxps://www.mysite.com/index.php/controller/action**

Comment: Because I have limited privileges on the server (Gandi hosting). mod_ssl is not available. The only way to force ssl was via mod_rewrite.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my comment. Your actions add "/index.php" into the url, and remove/disable the normal rewrite rules - you don't need to do that to solve the question. OR: rewriting http to https and normal url rewriting are two separate things - they aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hum, well. In fact, with the Cake-rewrite, I had bad redirections (coming from 'Auth-component'). This is the 'GET-trace' I put in my initial question. Now with /index.php, I don't know why, it works. Bug?

Comment: The auth component does not change protocol - if your app is configured to do this - then yes, it contains a bug =).

Comment: However, the only stuffs I changed were these things and now I got a nice 'trace'.