# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Cakephp running on Hostigator (Cpanel)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to force a cakephp App running on Cpanel using this:
(Modifying the .htaccess in the root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# FORCE SSL REDIRECTION
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The error is : ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have tried several solutions like this:
[Best pratice for SSL in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993337/best-pratice-for-ssl-in-cakephp)

***EDIT 1:***

In this post Says:

.htaccess --->

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Disabling URL-Rewriting in Cake
(Found it in: /app/config/core.php, added this line, nothing happens)

core.php --->

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

But I can't either make this app to work under https.

***EDIT2:***

I'm aware that there are 2 more ( /app/webroot/.htaccess and /app/.htaccess , and It looks like the first one is the one that gives redirection, if I rename it or delete it I've got another error: Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

***EDIT 3:***

Also tried this 3 method with no joy.
https://www.captiga.com/linux/redirect-http-to-https/

***EDIT 4***

Same result, modifying: public_html/app/app_controller.php
source: http://lithicstudios.com/force-https-ssl-with-php-cakephp/

```
//REDIRECT TO HTTPS IF REQUEST IS NOT HTTPS
if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on")
{
$redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
header("Location:$redirect");
exit;
}
```

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>`

Comment: Can you write it correctly as answer please ?